# Multiple charges to equal specified amount using Stripe

Tags: api, credit-card, stripe-payments

Getting confused on how I should set this up. Basically I need to charge a customer two separate amounts on two separate dates that they provide. They will be provided with a total and be able to choose which two dates they would like to be charged and how much on each date.

After reading through the DOCS and FAQS on Stripe's website all day, I think I might know how to tackle this.

1. Create a customer.
2. Setup a plan with the specified amount they want to pay and
   calculate how many days until they should be charged using
   **trial_end** to start on the specified date.
3. Listen for the first charge. Now cancel the current plan, take the second amount and
   preferred charge date (stored in database) and create a new plan. Again, using **trial_end** to charge on correct date provided.
4. Listen for the second charge and cancel this plan.

Is this an ideal way to accomplish what I want? Trying not to waste a bunch of time, have a tight deadline with this project. Appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the following.

1. Create a customer and store the customer token
2. Store the two dates in your database
3. Write a script the looks for one of the two dates and tries to run the charge with the customer token. Schedule it with cron or a similar scheduler.
4. On charge failure or denied, act accordingly
5. On success, delete the customer token, and act accordingly